# Call to a member function setCode() on a non-object error in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a cotroller action like

```
public function updateAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $codesArray=array('AFGHANISTAN;AF','ÅLAND ISLANDS;AX','ALBANIA;AL');
        foreach ($codesArray as $detail)
        {
            $detailArray=explode(";",$detail);
            $country=$em->getRepository('TestBundle:Countries')
                          ->findOneBy(array('name'=>$detailArray[0]));
            $country->setCode($detailArray[1]);
        }
        $em->flush();
    }
```

it shows error

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function setCode() on a non-object
```

but when i replace

```
$country=$em->getRepository('TestBundle:Countries')
                          ->findOneBy(array('name'=>$detailArray[0]));
```

with

```
$country=$em->getRepository('TestBundle:Countries')
                              ->find('1');
```

means it will update 1st record. please give me the solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repository ( and Entity ) names are normally singular.

If your entity class is Country you get your Repository with:

```
 $country=$em->getRepository('TestBundle:Country')-> ...
```

I don't know what you're trying to do but you can get those Country codes from the symfony2 [Intl component](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/intl.html#country-names) ...

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl;

\Locale::setDefault('en');

$countries = Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryNames();
// => array('AF' => 'Afghanistan', ...)

$country = Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryName('GB');
// => 'United Kingdom'
```

Comment: How can i achieve this in symfony2 @nifr          
`foreach ($codesArray as $detail)
     {
  $detailArray=explode(";",$detail);
  $query="update country set code=".$detailArray[1]." where name=".$detailArray[0];
 }`